# LDAP userPassword only works with plaintext

Tags: ldap, authentication, password, openldap

I have setup openLDAP server on an ubuntu machine.  I am trying to test user authentication, but am running into a problem.  If, in ldap, the userPassword contains a plaintext password, authentication works just fine.  However, if I set the value of userPassword to be a hashed password (like sha256), the authentication fails.  Do I need to tell openLDAP that I am using sha somewhere?

FYI, I am using openLDAP and Apache Directory Studio to interact with it.  I am testing authentication by trying to bind using a php script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FAQ, OpenLDAP releases prior to 2.4.32 do not support SHA-2 algorithms including SHA256. 2.4.32 and later releases need to be built with contrib/slapo-pw-sha2 to support SHA-2. You can use SHA-1 or Salted SHA-1 out of the box. Please see http://www.openldap.org/faq/index.cgi?file=1467 and http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html#Password+Storage for more.